# jQuery - console.log() returns an element but I can't access it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I happened to have super dumb issue and I'm stuck.

I do console.log(data) and I get exactly this:

```
<a href='http://www.someurl.com'>caption</a>
```

The question is how do I get this links "href" attribute.

I have absolutely no idea why, but these doesn't work:

`data.text()` == Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (should be: caption)

`$('a',data).attr('href')` == undefined (should be: http://www.someurl.com)

Maybe this is not a string, but object or something else? How to check that? My JS looks like this:

```
 window.send_to_editor = function(data) {
      var videourl = data;
      console.log(videourl.text()); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
      console.log(videourl);  // <a href='http://www.someurl.com'>caption</a>
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that it IS a string. The methods you're calling only work on jQuery objects, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can do something like that:

```
var data = "<a href='http://www.someurl.com'>caption</a>";
var link = $(data).attr('href');
```

It will create dynamically your DOM element, then you will be able to get your attribute href.

Comment: Gosh, I'm dumb I've been trying to convert it to an object but it wouldn't work then. It works now, so I blame typo. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should first find out, what type `data` is. To do this you can use the JavaScript builtin function `typeof(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) object. That is why it is undefined. First, [create a jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

```
var _videourl = $(videourl);
console.log(_videourl.text());
console.log(_videourl.attr('href'));
// caption (index)
// http://www.someurl.com
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/SfVw6/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, data is a string, not a jQuery object and therefore does not have of jQuery's methods (like `text`).

If you are certain that `data` is a string containing a link, you can use a regular expression to extract the link like so:

```
var match = data.match(/href='(.*)'/g);
url = match && match[1];
console.log(url);
```

Alternately, you can create a jQuery object from your string. But that's a much more expensive operation if you just want to get the url.